# How to integrate Prometheus with ReactiveFeignClient to meter response time/hits of each status code returned from client call

Tags: spring-webflux, prometheus-java, reactive-feign-client

I am with a Spring Boot project with WebFlux + Spring Reactor, and it calls other services with `ReactiveFeignClient`.

How can I integrate Prometheus so that I could monitor response time (with a `@Timer`) and the percentage of each status code returned by feign call? Like 200, 400, 404... I have only found ways to:

- monitor endpoint response time/status code(`http_server_requests_seconds`)
- monitor `RestTemplate` (as explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/prometheus, but I use feign)

After all the work I have done, I have seen no reactive feign clients meters in Prometheus output, even though I defined the bean of logger like:

```
    @Bean
    public MetricsWebClientFilterFunction metricsWebClientFilterFunction(PrometheusMeterRegistry meterRegistry,
                                                                         WebClientExchangeTagsProvider provider) {
        return new MetricsWebClientFilterFunction(
                meterRegistry,
                provider,
                APP_NAME + "reactive-client-request",
                AutoTimer.ENABLED
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public MicrometerReactiveLogger feignReactiveLogger(Clock clock,
                                                        PrometheusMeterRegistry meterRegistry) {

        return new MicrometerReactiveLogger(
                clock,
                meterRegistry,
                APP_NAME + ".feign.client_metrics",
                MetricsTag.getMandatory()
        );
    }
```

Also, I found it impossible to enable `/actuator/prometheus`, but only `/_system/check/prometheus`. I did enable and expose the endpoints of `metrics` and `prometheus`.

```
management:
  health:
    diskspace:
      enabled: false
  endpoint:
    metrics.enabled: true
    prometheus.enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /_system/check
      exposure:
        include: info,health,loggers,metrics,prometheus
      path-mapping:
        health: /simple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: the metrics related with reactive feign clients will only show after you actually do feign calls. Before that they are hidden.

Reactive Feign Client uses `WebClient` underneath and will be measured automatically with presence of Spring Actuator.